Case and When in ORM Django
I want to get the matching percentage between user skills and job skills.
the code:
def job_application_get_action(data, context):
    user_id: int = data.get("user_id", context["request"].user.id)

    # First, get the user's skills in a single query
    user_skills = set(
        SkillProficiency.objects.filter(user_id=user_id)
        .values_list("skill_id", flat=True)
    )
    print(user_skills)

    # Now, query the jobs with a count of matched skills
    jobs = (
        CandiadteApplication.objects.filter(user_id=user_id)
        .values(
            title=F("job_vacancy__roles__job_profile__title"),
            company_name=F("job_vacancy__company_name"),
            application_date=F("created_at"),
        )
        .annotate(
            skills=ArrayAgg("job_vacancy__roles__skills__skill_ref", distinct=True),
            count_job_skills=Count("job_vacancy__roles__skills__skill_ref", distinct=True),
            matched_skills_count=Count(
                Case(
                    When(job_vacancy__roles__skills__skill_ref__in=user_skills, then=1),
                ),
                distinct=True
            ),
        )
        .annotate(
            matched_percentage=Case(
                When(count_job_skills__gt=0, 
                     then=F('matched_skills_count') * 100 / F('count_job_skills')),
                default=0,
                output_field=IntegerField(),
            )
        )
    )

    payload = list(jobs)
    print(payload)

    return {
        "success": True,
        "message": "job applications are fetched successfully",
        "payload": payload,
    }


and the output:
user_skills: {'399', '9282', '11225', '3679', '6535', '10754', '10930', '39', '2186', '8531', '409', '2848', '3338', '1370', 
'3924', '406', '398', '11127', '13529', '12298'}

[{'title': 'Java', 'company_name': 'Adepti', 'application_date': datetime.datetime(2024, 7, 28, 15, 1, 20, 245422, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc), 
'skills': ['12573', '1370', '3338', '6535'], 'count_job_skills': 4, 'matched_skills_count': 1, 'matched_percentage': 25}, {'title': 'Python', 'company_name': 'new company', 'application_date': datetime.datetime(2024, 7, 28, 14, 25, 0, 572424, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc), 
'skills': ['11127'], 'count_job_skills': 1, 'matched_skills_count': 1, 'matched_percentage': 100}, {'title': 'Video Editor', 'company_name': 'TechNova', 'application_date': datetime.datetime(2024, 7, 25, 
16, 28, 56, 531933, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc), 'skills': ['6961', '7883'], 'count_job_skills': 2, 'matched_skills_count': 0, 'matched_percentage': 0}]

I notice that Case When matches only first value it found that it matching with the user skills and ignore the rest.
for example:
in job java the matching percentahe should be 75% but it displayed 25%.
How can Case When compare alll values?

I solved it by remove distinct=True
